# Working with two date fields - how can I select seven days or less from one date field towards another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Essentially, I have two date columns- one "leave_date" and another one called "return_date", and I want to filter on the users that have returned from their leave date (leave_date) before seven days or less.

```
SELECT profile_id, did_churn, leave_date, return_date
from table
where did_churn= 'true'
and leave_date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28'
and return_date <= DATEADD(day,7, leave_date)
```

However, I am not getting the results I need:

For example, this one profile ID (ex. M5k294l21i4h) has a leave_date of 2022-02-25, but it's returning the return_date of 2020-03-01. Clearly that's not right.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL because that function syntax doesn't look like MySQL....

Comment: mysql has no DATEADD function.  please show your actual working query, or tag the correct database

Comment: What values it suppose to return? You know that `2020-03-01` is within 7 days from `2022-02-25`.. it's February.. Or maybe I'm understanding it wrong. Can you update [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6059430b2ffb3b81f7de9652603a37a5) click "Run" then post the new generated link into your question?

Comment: @FanoFN - I thought that at first too, but then noticed the year is 2020 instead of 2022 :-)

Comment: Omg @SOS , how did I miss that!?? I even copy paste the date in my comment but failed to notice it, how embarassing lol.

Comment: @FanoFN - Heh, happens to me too. Especially at the end of the day, lol!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp):

```
SELECT profile_id, did_churn, leave_date, return_date
from table
where did_churn= 'true'
and leave_date BETWEEN '2022-02-01' and '2022-02-28'
and DATEDIFF(return_date, leave_date) <= 7
```